# How to trigger onchange event of all input at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have an input that is automatically created or generated when a specific button is clicked...

And let's say the generated inputs are...

```
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='functionName($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='anotherFunctionName($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='newFunctionName($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='anotherNewFunctionName($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='datetime-local' onchange='...($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='...($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='text' onchange='...($id,this.value)' />
<input class='myinput' type='datetime-local' onchange='...($id,this.value)' />
...
```

Those inputs have different types and specific functions are being called on the `OnChange` event. Sometimes it doesn't need to change the value, my problem is it will only save the data on the `OnChange` event.

It is possible to trigger the `OnChange` event on those inputs at once using javascript or jquery?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: May I ask why you want to trigger onchange on all the inputs?

Comment: @ProsyArceno because sometimes there is no need to change the default value of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with class name using Trigger,

```
$('.myinput').trigger("Click");
```

Check out this link https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Since the input is dynamically generated, how can I use the trigger function?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$('input[type=text]').trigger('change');
```

Comment: The OP said **inputs have different types**, I think you should use class instead

Comment: Since the input is dynamically generated, how can I use the trigger function?